# How to avoid insert, delete, update anomaly in MySql

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables like this
**Table1: manager**

```html
 =======================================
|| Id || MgrName  || department         ||
=========================================
|| 1  || mgr1     ||human resource      ||
|| 2  || mgr2     ||marketing           ||
|| 3  || mgr3     ||customer management ||
=========================================
```

**Table2: employee**

```html
====================================
|| empid   || empname || empmanager||
====================================
|| 1       || abc     ||  mgr1     ||
|| 2       || xyz     ||  mgr1     ||
|| 3       || def     ||  mgr3     ||
=====================================
```

The thing is when I delete `mgr1` in `table1:manager`. I also want to update `employee` table where `empmanager` is `mgr1` by `null`. I don't want to use any *trigger*.

Please tell me proper way to design database and also to avoid this problem.

Comment: The keyword here is `FOREIGN KEY`.

Comment: if i use foreign key i will not able to delete manager entry also

Comment: If you define a foreign key, you also define, what happens, if the referred key gets deleted. One option there is to set the foreign key value to null. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

You should follow normalization rules to avoid anomalies while performing CRUD operations,

1. First Normal Form
2. Second Normal Form
3. Third Normal Form

please refer these links to apply normalization to you tables [link 1](http://searchbusinessintelligence.techtarget.in/tutorial/Database-normalization-in-MySQL-Four-quick-and-easy-steps) [link 2](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html)

Comment: I think normalization causes anomaly. Normalization is used to reduce inconsistency and redundancy of data. I think sirko is right i should go for foreign key.